# Find equal brob numbers using the R package Brobdingnag

Tags: r

I am trying to find when two numbers of class brob are equal, but I guess this does not work because of the precision stored in these numbers that is not shown. For example, I have two numbers:

```
a= 634.7984
b= 641.71

library(Brobdingnag)
a_brob = as.brob(exp(1))^a = +exp(634.8)
b_brob = as.brob(exp(1))^b*0.001 = +exp(634.8)
```

I would like to output TRUE in this condition:

```
 a_brob==b_brob
>[1] FALSE
```

But I get FALSE.I also tried using 'numeric' or double or rounding them, but nothign works. Can you please help?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you get FALSE because your brobs aren't equals, event they are printed by the same number.

Use `dput` to see this :

```
> library(Brobdingnag)
> (a_brob <- as.brob(exp(1))^a )
[1] +exp(634.8)
> (b_brob <- as.brob(exp(1))^b*0.001)
[1] +exp(634.8)
> (dput(a_brob))
new("brob"
    , x = 634.7984
    , positive = TRUE
)
NULL
> (dput(b_brob))
new("brob"
    , x = 634.802244721018
    , positive = TRUE
)
NULL
```

Comment: Sorry... I was trying to take the log of the difference: log(a_brob-b_brob) and wasn't able to so I thought the reason was because the difference was actually zero...Does anybody know how to actually compute this logarithm then? Thank you!

Comment: @user971102 `log(a_brob-b_brob)` returns NAN because the argument is negatif! try `log(b_brob-a_brob)` or `log(abs((a_brob-b_brob)))`

Comment: But I really need this difference and not the opposite...I am not sure why this difference is negative, maybe due to approximations, but basically I wanted to give me a FALSE when these numbers are the same or very close by to each other such as this case I guess...

Comment: I would something like `as.numeric(abs((1-b_brob/a_brob)))`  and compare it to 0.001 for example ...